# SQL Server Select columns from joined tables plus counts in same select statement

Tags: sql, count, group-by

Currently I am performing 3 separate SQL calls. I would like to combine them into one if possible so my grid will sort properly.

I am working with 4 separate Tables

BlastAnalytics - has the following columns and bold are the ones I need the values...
    id(primaryKey), **eventType, BlastID, email, ts, bounceDesc**

BlastJobs - has the following columns and bold are the ones I need the values...
    JobNumber(primaryKey), **MessageFrom, MessageHeader**

BlastOpens - id(primaryKey), AnalyticsID, ts

BlastClicks - id(primaryKey), AnalyticsID, ts

The Joins are...
    BlastAnalytics.BlastID --> BlastJobs.JobNumber
    BlastAnalytics.id --> BlastOpens.AnalyticsID
    BlastAnalytics.id --> BlastClicks.AnalyticsID

Currently I run the following SQL Statement to bind my grid...

```
SELECT BlastAnalytics.eventType, BlastAnalytics.BlastID, BlastAnalytics.email, 
  BlastAnalytics.ts, BlastAnalytics.bounceDesc, BlastJobs.MessageFrom, 
  BlastJobs.MessageHeader
FROM BlastAnalytics INNER JOIN
  BlastJobs ON BlastAnalytics.BlastID = BlastJobs.JobNumber
WHERE (BlastAnalytics.eventType <> 'open') 
 AND (BlastAnalytics.eventType <> 'click') 
 AND (BlastAnalytics.BlastID = @BlastID)
ORDER BY BlastAnalytics.ts DESC
```

Then on grid1_RowDataBound (when each individual row is created) I run the follow statements to get my Counts...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS OpenCount, BlastAnalytics.email
FROM BlastAnalytics INNER JOIN
  BlastOpens ON BlastAnalytics.id = BlastOpens.AnalyticsID
WHERE (BlastAnalytics.BlastID = @BlastID) 
  AND (BlastAnalytics.email = @email)

SELECT COUNT(*) AS ClickCount, BlastAnalytics.email
FROM BlastAnalytics INNER JOIN
  BlastClicks ON BlastAnalytics.id = BlastClicks.AnalyticsID
WHERE (BlastAnalytics.BlastID = @BlastID) 
  AND (BlastAnalytics.email = @email)
```

This all works fine but I would think I should be able to combine those statements into one using GROUP BYs or something, but I can't figure out how.

**EDIT**

Here is an example of the type of data in the tables...

BlastOpens Table

```
id     AnalyticsID    ts     BlastID
2958   38289   1358546399   479
2959   38852   1358546391   479
2960   38280   1358546391   479
2961   38280   1358546400   479
2965   38282   1358546396   480
2986   38284   1358546398   480
```

BlastAnalytics Table

```
id  eventType   BlastID   email   ts   bounceDesc
38280   open   479  blahblah@blah.com   1358546555  NULL
38289   open   479  blahblah@blah.com   1358546555  NULL
38352   open   479  itsa@test.com   1358550528  NULL
38115   send   479  blahblah@blah.com   1358545375  NULL
```

So in the example above blahblah@blah.com has a total Open Count of 3 and itsa@test.com has 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I haven't tested this, something like this should work assuming your RDBMS supports sub queries:

```
SELECT BlastAnalytics.eventType, BlastAnalytics.BlastID, BlastAnalytics.email, 
   BlastAnalytics.ts, BlastAnalytics.bounceDesc, BlastJobs.MessageFrom, 
   BlastJobs.MessageHeader, 
   BO.OpenCount,
   BC.ClickCount
FROM BlastAnalytics 
   INNER JOIN BlastJobs ON BlastAnalytics.BlastID = BlastJobs.JobNumber
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS OpenCount, BlastAnalytics.BlastID, BlastAnalytics.email
      FROM BlastAnalytics INNER JOIN
         BlastOpens ON BlastAnalytics.id = BlastOpens.AnalyticsID
      GROUP BY BlastAnalytics.BlastID, BlastAnalytics.email
   ) BO ON BlastAnalytics.BlastID = BO.BlastID AND BlastAnalytics.Email = BO.Email
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS ClickCount, BlastAnalytics.BlastID, BlastAnalytics.email
      FROM BlastAnalytics INNER JOIN
         BlastClicks ON BlastAnalytics.id = BlastClicks.AnalyticsID
      GROUP BY BlastAnalytics.BlastID, BlastAnalytics.email
   )  BC ON BlastAnalytics.BlastID = BC.BlastID AND BlastAnalytics.Email = BC.Email
WHERE (BlastAnalytics.eventType <> 'open') 
   AND (BlastAnalytics.eventType <> 'click') 
   AND (BlastAnalytics.BlastID = @BlastID)
ORDER BY BlastAnalytics.ts DESC
```

Good luck.

Comment: We're close but I'm getting 0's returned for the counts. The issue is I'm getting this data from some Mandrill web hooks and they send me entries for sends, rejects, opens, clicks, bounces...etc. I don't want to show the actual opens and clicks records in the grid but the associated opens,clicks totals for each of the send records grouped by the email address.

Comment: I made an Edit above showing a small example of the data in the tables. There can be multiple Open entries in the BlastOpens table for each associated open record in the BlastAnalytics table.

Comment: So for each of the ids in the BlastAnalytics table (38280, 38289, 38115), you should be getting an Open Count of 3?

Comment: No 38280 gets an open count of 2, 38289 gets a count of 1 and 38115 should get a count of 1. When you combine them I want to display the 'send' record of blahblah@blah.com (38115) with a open count of 3 (38280+38289) and the 'send' record of itsa@test.com (id not shown in table above) with an open count of 1 (38352).

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answers (and fixed the issue with the 1st one).  Good luck.

Comment: I will keep working on it. Unfortunately the way I have my tables setup it is not very simple. Your example doesn't use the proper joins. If you look at my tables above my Opens table doesn't have a BlastID or Email column. I tried changing your code using my join from BlastAnalytics.id to BlastOpens.AnalyticsID for both the Opens and Clicks table and I ended up with zeros for the click total. I'm not sure that this can be done.

Comment: It's working fine the way I am doing it, Getting the count row by row. I was just hoping I could do it in one query so I didn't have to do it individually like that. My grid only processes 15 rows at a time so it's not that huge of a hit. The only issue is doing it this way I can't sort my grid by Opens or Clicks.

Comment: That's it!!! Now I just have to go in and figure out what you did. Thanks a ton. I was losing hope here.

Comment: I would Vote you up but as a newbie on here I don't have the Rep to do it yet.

Comment: I just gave you +1 for the question :-)